# Socket Program in C++ to send a message back and forth between server and client

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I am Trying to make a C/C++ Project using Socket Programming.

For this I need Client and Server to sent a index of array back and forth to each other.

So Client will next a index of array and server will sent another index of array until the game is over. (Yeah we are trying to make a game.)

I have written (copied from gfg) code for it but it's not working properly.

The Server for some reason didn't receive the second message. So, We kind of stuck in a deadlock.

Any idea what I did wrong??

Server.cpp

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define PORT 8080

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in address; 
    int opt = 1; 
    int addrlen = sizeof(address); 
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
    char *msg = "0"; 

    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) 
    { 
        perror("socket failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, 
                                                  &opt, sizeof(opt))) 
    { 
        perror("setsockopt"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT ); 

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,  
                                 sizeof(address))<0) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) 
    { 
        perror("listen"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,  
                       (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) 
    { 
        perror("accept"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }
    int i=0;
    while(i<10)
    {
        valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024); 
        printf("%s\n",buffer ); 
        send(new_socket , msg , strlen(msg) , 0 ); 
        printf("Message sent\n");
        i++;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Client.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define PORT 8080 

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    int sock = 0, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
    char *msg="0"; 
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)  
    { 
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n"); 
        return -1; 
    }

    int i=0;
    while(i<10)
    {
        send(sock , msg , strlen(msg) , 0 ); 
        printf("Message sent\n"); 
        valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024); 
        printf("%s\n",buffer );
        i++;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Edit: It will be really nice if somebody can tell me how to sent an integer instead of a string.

Comment: Considering using debugger on the server (and or the client) to find out where exactly is the server and client waiting. Also, what is the message that you want to send - code only sending string with "0".

Comment: `(socklen_t*)&addrlen`? Why are you using `int` for `addrlen`?  If `socklen_t` isn't the same size as `int`, you've written broken code.  Making errors and warnings disappear by casting is a very bad way to write code.

Comment: The last line of the `while` loop in the client and server is just `msg;` - what is that supposed to achieve?  By the way, `const char *msg="0";` is safer.

Comment: Compilation fail.  Failure to correctly and completely handle the result returned by system calls.  Calling library functions that require NUL-terminated char arrays as an argument with arrays that are not guaranteed NUL-terminated.  Failure to understand the octet-stream nature of TCP and so expecting 'messages' longer than a byte.  All the usual suspects:(

Comment: I am so sorry as @cdarke pointed out the "msg;" was the problem.

Comment: @dash-o - I want to sent a index of an array. I couldn't figure out how to sent an int.

Comment: @MartinJames - Sorry man, but it compiled for me.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I am very much new to socket programming. I had no idea what I was doing as I don't fully understand the inbuild functions/library functions used in socket programming. Any idea how to fix it? All I need is to sent an int (a number between 1-9).